# How to use a WCF Service Library in a solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know how to create a restful web service using WCF. If i create the service as a "WCF Service Library" and implement it in a solution, how do i activate it, when it is not the main project?

I am using a N-tiered architecture. The webservice should have access to some layers below it, while clients from the outside should be able to call the webservice.

What is the best way to host a service in my case ? Windows Service? IIS ? Self-hosting?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thera are various options to host your wcf service , theory behind each option is detailed here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx

It looks like you don't have any hosting code , in that case hosting using iis is your best option as all other options require you to have some hosting code I.e. a main entry point.

For iis you just have to create a web application project as instructed in the iis hosting section in the following article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/150066/Create-Host-Self-Hosting-IIS-hosting-and-Consume-W

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways I think:

- Visual Studio can host the service for you if you want (It should have set this up automatically)

[image: Visual Studio WCF config]

- Create a separate Console project where you host your WCF Service. Then change the solution to have multiple start-up projects, so that you can start both your app and the console for WCF. More info about self hosting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a solution to start multiple projects. Here is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) link for this.